# Former employee registered corporate domain to themselves

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar, domain-registration

Not sure if serverfault is the right place for this question but I'm at my wits end.

I work for Company A.  A former employee registered our corporate domain (`a.com`) to their personal email at `name@theirLastName.com`.

They have since left the company and absconded into the wilderness (literally).  They left on good terms and are still a major shareholder but I have no way of getting in touch with them (tried every social media account, former phone numbers, family, etc.)

Since then, they have let their domain (`theirLastName.com`) expire.  Because the contact info on our corporate domain, `a.com`, expired, the domain registrar has suspended the domain, even though it is still paid for.

Do I have any options for recovering `a.com`?  I have loads of incorporation paperwork for `Company A`, proof of the former co-worker being employed there, proof of who the executives are, etc etc, but the registrar is saying they can only work with the original registrant.

In the mean time, someone else has purchased `theirlastname.com`, meaning the owner of that domain, if they knew, could easily set up that email address and take our domain name, which the company paid a lot of money for.

Comment: Is the TLD `.com` or is that just a placeholder? Some TLD owners are subject to reasonably attainable court orders mandating ownership transwer.

Comment: There's the UDRP process but this can take a few weeks. Have you considered sending out search parties? It would be much easier to recover the domain if the registrant can be found, alive or dead.

Comment: @anx just a placeholder.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have consulted with a Private Investigator because it seemed to be the only realistic option available.

Comment: "the domain registrar has suspended the domain, even though it is still paid for."  Why is it suspended if paid for?

Comment: "Normally" with enough proofs, especially about the payment for the domain, the registrar could be willing to change things. What is the registrant name? The employee or the company? If it is the company it should not be a problem to amend the records.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Unfortunately the registrant is the employee.